# Can we find two other angles of a triangle if we have only one angle?

Tags: mathematica

Can we find two other angles of a triangle if we have only one angle? If yes, then how?

Comment: If 1 angle is the only known thing, then no.

Comment: With $60º$, you can make a 60-60-60 triangle, or a 60-90-30 triangle, or a 60-59-61 triangle. There are many more counterexamples with different angles.

Comment: By the way, there is absolutely no research effort in this question.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of all angles of a triangle is constant. On a plane of curvature of zero (a Euclidian plane or flat plane), this is equal to 180 degrees.
ie.
$$180^{\circ} = \theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3$$

In your case you know $\theta_1$ but $\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$ are unknown. This results in one equation with two unknowns.

Thus when one angle is given there is more information needed to find the other two angles.

Answer (score 0):

If two triangles are similar, they have the same angles. The criteria needed for similarity of the other triangle are:

$$\text{AA or AAA (at least $2$ angles known)}$$
$$\text{SSS (all $3$ sides known)}$$
$$\text{SAS ($2$ sides and the angle in between is known)}$$

Since one angle known is not in the criteria needed for similarity, you cannot find the two other angles. As ElderNoSpace wrote, you need at least $1$ other angle to find these angles.